# how to fix this roblox script unknown error

Tags: roblox

I'm getting a script error in the console saying I need a "}" near line 4.
The fifth parameter there is a error, and idk how to fix it:

```
local args = {
    [1] = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer.Character,
    [2] = workspace.NPCs["Harlow Auburn"],
    [3] = "Ice Magic",
    [4] = "3",
    [5] = "["Blast Attack",1,90,100,false,"Two Hands","(None)","Blast","Ice","Ice"]",
    [6] = 0,
}

game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").RS.Remotes.Magic.DealAttackDamage:FireServer(unpack(args))
```

Comment: I have no idea of Roblox so take this with a grain of salt, but are you sure the comma after `[6] = 0,` (last line of the array) is correct?

Comment: @Taschi trailing commas are fine in lua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a syntax error.

If `[5]` is supposed to be a single string, then you need to properly escape your string values :

```
[5] = "[\"Blast Attack\",1,90,100,false,\"Two Hands\",\"(None)\",\"Blast\",\"Ice\",\"Ice\"]",
```

If `[5]` is supposed to be an array of values, then you need to define it as a table.

```
[5] = {"Blast Attack",1,90,100,false,"Two Hands","(None)","Blast","Ice","Ice"},
```